# Best practice so switch between a grid and list layout at runtime

Tags: sapui5

Im currently working on a project where I want to the user to be able to chose between two layouts (list and grid) at runtime. I was searching for examples in the UI5 documentation (Sample Apps) and on GitHub, I did not find examples for how to to this or best practice examples. So I thought about how I could achieve this behaviour and had multiple ideas, but somehow none of them feels like doing this would be best practice.

**Idea 1 - Destroy the "old" controls and generate the new controls inside the Controller**
My first idea was to destory the controls I do not longer need. For example if the user wants to switch to the grid layout, the list and every control related it to it gets destoyed. In the controller the needed controls for the grid are created and then rendered in the view. In my eyes this would mix up view and controller logic inside the controller and does not feel like best practice

**Idea 2 - Create two views and switch between them**
My second idea was to create two views, each for the layout I need and switch between them. This would mean a lot of code replication in both the controller and the view. Does not feel like this would be the right way.

So I would be glad if you have own experience on this or if there is really something like a best practice for such a behaviour.

Thank you and kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would say, idea 2 because of the following reasons:**

1. It is best practice to work according to the **MVC methodology** which means separating logic, view and data. Since the controls define your view it is best to instantiate your controls in the files that are meant for it (the XML Views).
2. **Performance**: Destroying all controls means that if the user decides to switch between views, the controls have to be re-instantiated by the controller every time. This is, even though you probably won't notice it, not performant.
3. **You don't need code replication**: The argument of code replication is not necessarily true. If you can execute the same actions in the list and grid-view, it should be enough to just link the controller to both views and in that case you'll hardly have to replicate any code. Just make sure that you split your logic in enough functions. That way you might need to write some extra public functions to handle events, but not much more.